# Excel Hours/Minutes Difference Between Two Date Time Fields

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I dont use Excel to do any calculations but is there a way to calculate the Hours Minutes between two date time fields?

E.g From Date 24/08/2021 04:03 and To Date 25/08/2021 06:08.

I need to show this as 26:05

Thanks

Comment: what (method/tool) had u tried?

Answer (score 1):

Substract end date with start date, format cell [h]:mm and that's it.
[image]